# How to dynamically set the commit-interval in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

When I tried to assign a value from jobExecutioncontext to commit-interval am getting the below error.

```
<chunk reader="itemREader" writer="itemwriter" commit-interval="#{jobExecutionContext[rowcount]}">

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

same error am getting when pulled from jobParameters.

Tried using chunk-completion-policy by creating a custom policy class extending SimpleCompletionPolicy and passing the value from jobExecutioncontext. When I run the job the step is started but not completing keep on running.

```
 <bean id="myCompletionPolicy"
          class="com.vn.src.service.myCompletionPolicy" scope="step">
        <property name="recordCount" value="#{jobExecutionContext[RowCount]}"/>
    </bean>
```

myCompletionPolicy class:

```
public class myCompletionPolicy extends SimpleCompletionPolicy {

    private String recordCount;

    public MapCpeBatchFileJobCompletionPolicy() {

        setChunkSize(Integer.valueOf(recordCount));

    }

    public void setRecordCount(String recordCount) {
        this.recordCount = recordCount;
    }
}
```

Could someone please let me know how can the commit-interval value can be set dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: Your class will of course never work... The value is going to be set after the call to the constructor. Also you don't need your own implementation you can just create an instance of the `SimpleCompletionPolicy` and use an expression to set the `chunkSize` property. You are making it way to complex. Also why would you want to set it dynamically?

Comment: This spring batch job will read from a table and will create a file, the file should contain either all the records, if any exception occurred then the file should be empty, so i need to dynamically set the commit-interval based on the no of rows retrieved from the table.

Comment: I tried creating an instance of simple completion policy and tried to set the chunksize but there am getting cannot convert string to int error as the values from jobExecutionContext will be string.                                                                                                             <bean id="myCompletionPolicy"
          class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.SimpleCompletionPolicy" scope="step">
        <property name="chuncksize" value="#{jobExecutionContext[RowCount]}"/>
    </bean>

Comment: So basically you are using batch but aren't using any of the benefits... Instead of meddling with a commit count isn't it easier to create a `JobListener` or `StepListener` which based on the outcome either keeps the file or nukes the file...

Comment: creating an instance of the SimpleCompletionPolicy and use an expression to set the chunkSize property is working fine. Thanks.